# primefaces mobile and desktop

Tags: mobile, primefaces, prettyfaces

I have a working desktop application written in Primefaces and PrettyFaces. To include for mobile, I have followed the solution suggested on [their forum](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=19887).
My requirement is in one of the many pages, I want to expose certain pages (screens) just for mobile and in a phased approach, the rest of the pages will be migrated later.

In prettyfaces config file,

```
<url-mapping id="home">
    <pattern value="/home" />
    <action>#{homeBean.renderView}</action>     
    <view-id>/xhtml/home/home.xhtml</view-id>
</url-mapping>
```

and in HomeBean,

```
public String renderView(){
    String renderKitId = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getRenderKitId();        
    System.out.println("renderKitId:::"+renderKitId);
    if(renderKitId.equalsIgnoreCase("PRIMEFACES_MOBILE")){
        return "/mobile_xhtml/home/home.xhtml";
    }else{
        return "/xhtml/home/home.xhtml";
    }
}
```

This is rendering properly for mobile and desktop.
But when I click on other links, the page is not submitted and only the home page is rendered.
My questions are

1. Why is that other links are not working?
2. How can I seamlessly render mobile pages for certain screens and remaining screens as basic HTML?

Hope I was clear in explaining the problem.
Thanks!